# Lua - How to use constants with vars?

Tags: lua, constants, member

I don't really have a clue of lua so sry if this is dumb ^^'

I have a constants(?) like this:

```
Config.name
```

It content is "true" or "false". I set this constant-name(or member name?) dynamicly, so it can be for example: Config.george, Config.steve or Config.tim.
Now I want to check this constant, but I don't know how the syntax is.

I want something like this:

```
for _, friend in pairs(friends) do
    if Config.friend.name then
        print("He is checked!")
    end
end
```

The "friend.name" should be the name of that friend, george for example.
How is that done?

Comment: Are you asking how to compare values to each other? eg. `Config.friend.name == "george"`?

Comment: No, the friend.name should be george, or something else. the Config.george is an var (or constant, ot member.. I don't know in lua) and is true or false..

Comment: So you want to check whether `Config` has a key set to true with the key being whatever `friend.name` is? Like something like this for example? `if Config[friend.name] then`

Comment: Yes, kind of. But the value is set as a member I think(seperated by a dot) it is not an array with an index or something. Like i set Config.george = true and then I want to check if Config.george is like true. But I'm doing it in a loop where I don't know the name yet, so i need a dynamic way to call Config.whatever

Comment: `Config.george` is just syntax sugar for `Config['george']`. They're semantically the same. If those two pointers still don't fully solve your issue, you'll need to add some more context code that shows what you're trying to do.

Comment: Yes? oO So 'Config[friend.name]' should work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you're checking whether a given name is set to true in the `Config` table. Assuming `friends` is a table of names you want to check against, the code would be:

```
local friends = { 'george', 'steve', 'tim', } 
-- ...
for _, friend in pairs(friends) do
  if Config[friend] then
    print(friend.." is checked!")
  end
end
```

Note that `ipairs` can also work here or just iterate by index:

```
for i = 1, #friends do
  if Config[ friends[i] ] then
    print(friends[i] .. " is checked!")
  end
end
```